# LimeSurvey - Saving Changes To A Template

Tags: permissions, http-status-code-404, permission-denied, limesurvey

I am trying to make changes to a template but when I try to save changes, I receive the following error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /survey2/index.php/admin/templates/sa/templatesavechanges on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to > handle the request.

When I look in the templates folder, I do not see the templates I have created even though they are visible from within the LimeSurvey administration panel. Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have given write permissions to the upload and tmp directory inside your limesurvey installation.
I think this should solve your problem.

amit

Comment: I believe you accidentally answered my other Lime Survey question here.

Comment: This answer actually belongs to the question - as it seems that your template path is not writeable. I suggested a check for these paths on http://bugs.limesurvey.org/view.php?id=8252